# How to combine several rows into one based on a similar key in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 | Platform_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | 38.33 | nan | nan | nan | nan | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1.83 | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | nan | nan | nan | 5 | nan | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | nan | nan | 2.21 | nan | nan | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | nan | 20.83 | nan | nan | nan | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |

And I want to combine all these rows (there are 5 in the example, but more in the real dataset) and columns (also more than shown in the dataset below) based on the platform key. So like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 | Platform_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amazonwebservicesaws | asiapacificmumbai | 38.33 | 20.83 | 2.21 | 5 | 1.83 | amazonwebservicesaws_asiapacificmumbai |

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: will it always be the case that column 3 has a value in only one row and is nan in all the rest? and that same thing for all of columns 3-7? if two rows have values for a column, which value do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just `groupby` with `first` , which will pick the first not `NaN` value per col

```
out = df.groupby(['Platform_key'],as_index=False).first()
```